# Асинхронное выполнение функций в ExtJS

Tags: extjs, promise

Привет, коллеги!

Имеется следующая проблема при работе с **ExtJS 6.2** ... Один контроллер, в нем две довольно большие функции. Одна функция получает данные от сервера и обрабатывает их, вторая - строит некий базовый набор полей в форме. Код приводить смысла нет, ибо проблема не в коде, а в результатах выполнения.

После того как отработала первая функция (получение данных, обработка данных) данные должны наполнить форму, которая создается второй функцией.

Запуск первой функции осуществляется через роутер, при вызове метода в свойстве before.
Запуск второй функции осуществляется в методе свойства action.

Впервые я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что обе функции отрабатывают за одинаковое количество времени (2-3 секунды), при этом отрабатывают асинхронно. В результате я вижу, что то первая отработала раньше второй, то вторая раньше первой.

Собственно, хотелось бы понять, как сделать мои функции "условно" синхронными. Было бы чудесно оставить все как есть, но совместить их в результате выполнения, когда и форма отрендерилась, и данные сформированы, и только после этого выполнять setValues().

Вижу необходимость применения promise, но в Эксте ни разу с ними напрямую не работал... Кто подскажет разумный способ решить мою проблему? Ну только без таймаутов и отложенного выполнения)

Спасибо!

Comment: Событие сделайте. Первая функция после выполнения триггерит событие, на которое повешена вторая функция.Тогда они будут выполнятся последовательно

Comment: Синхронное выполнение увеличит время выполнения в два раза (сначала первая, ждем результат. Потом вторая, ждем результат). В идеале хотелось быть видеть их асинхронными, но по факту выполнения обеих - вызывать третий метод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const deferreds = [];
const promise1 = new Promise(resolve => deferreds.push({resolve}));
const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => deferreds.push({resolve}));

Promise.all([promise1,promise2]).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  // Обе функции отработали. Можно приступать к дальнейшим действиям
});

function first(){
  // Код код код
  deferreds[0].resolve(1);
}
function second(){
  // Код код код
  deferreds[1].resolve(2);
}

// Запускаем в рандомном порядке
setTimeout(first, Math.random() * 1500);
setTimeout(second, Math.random() * 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась с помощью Ext.deffered и использовании конструкции вида

```
func_one.then(
    func_two.then(
        this.callResultFunction();
    )
);
```

Ext.deffered объявляется в каждой функции (func_one, func_two), функции возвращают

```
var deferred = new Ext.Deferred();
deferred.resolve(); 
return deferred.promise;
```

Ну и все заработало как следует =) 
Спасибо